# Large fig tree fruit rotting on tree and falling all over the ground

Tags: figs, rot

[image]

[image][image][image][image]

The fig tree has been producing an incredible amount of fruit. Unfortunately all the fruit is rotting before it even falls from the tree. It smells like rancid rotting fruit all the time outside, and raking up and cleaning up all the dead fruit off the ground is an endless battle. I dont think trying to spray this entire tree for bugs is possible really, and treating all of the soil is really feasible for us either.

At this point we just want to stop it from fruiting if possible, maybe using some "Growth Regulator/Fruit growth prevention" type sprays.

We dont want to kill or chop down the tree, we wont be living here forever, we just want to get it under control while we are living here.

I just wanted to get some of your advice and feedback  on my fig tree situation.

Thanks!

Comment: And you don't want to harvest the figs when they're ripe?

Comment: I think it is normal. All my figs do so. You should harvest from tree, and discard the overripe fruits. Probably because of hot summer, the figs ripped earlier. Removing the fruits from ground it is not complex: you never have 100% removal, but if you do it 2 to 3 times per week, for 5 minutes per tree, you will have good results.